Cross compiling for AArch64 with Clang built from source
I'm trying to cross compile to AArch64 using clang on Ubuntu. I've installed the right packages and am able to compile successfully using a pre-packaged clang, but doing the same with a self built version causes errors over missing header files or libraries. For example:
simulator/fileoutscalarmgr.cc:22:10: fatal error: 'fstream' file not found
   22 | #include <fstream>

I'm able to fix these by manually specifying include paths (I don't have to do this with pre-packaged clang), but compilation still fails at linking which I can't fix.
The outputs of clang -v when setting --sysroot=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu and --target=aarch64-linux-gnu do not match for the pre-packaged and self built clang versions. Pre-packaged is able to find everything automatically:
Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/12
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/12
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64

While the one built from source cannot find the cross compiler libraries (has no matching output when using -v).
How can I get the clang built from source to find these libraries?

Are you specifying --sysroot? And --target?

Yes, both of these. Again it works fine with pre-packaged clang so my configuration is correct, it's just how I'm building my own version that's somehow wrong.

Probably you have different defaults. Maybe it's -stdlib=libc++ vs -stdlib=libstdc++?

@HolyBlackCat No change in behavior between those two, is there a way to find any other default flags clang might be using though?

@HolyBlackCat prepackaged clang does actually stop working with libc++. added some info in an edit.

Ubuntu uses API from Debian, so you can apt-get source ... to get at the package, including all build infos like flags or paths. That way you'd just have to compare your and their build. My guess: You need a cross-compiled C++ standard library as well.

@UlrichEckhardt Struggling to find anything relevant with what apt source clang provides, are you able to point me in the right direction? I definitely already have an aarch64 libstdc++ installed.

Managed to solve the problem! Inexplicitly, removing --sysroot=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu causes the clang built from source to work. When just using --target=aarch64-linux-gnu it works fine. Pre-packaged is still able to work with sysroot set for some reason though.
